# How to create Array of forms in java me

Tags: java-me, lcdui

I need to create an array of multiple forms, the code below doesn't seem to be working . .

```
private Form[] myForm3;

myForm3[0] = new Form("Course grade points in each sem " );

Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(myForm3[0]);
```

I am actually trying to create a form which accepts no of courses in each semester, and the grade in each course of each semester, I wanted to take input of grades of course of a semester each  in a separate form ( each form would have semester, no. of courses and respective grades), now I got to create those many separate semester forms based on user input . .

The idea I have is to create a function with form array in it, call the same function to display next form with necessary changes accordingly

I tried a lot, struck with array of forms, it does not seem to be working. . I have not used threads either, can this be used in any way?

Any other idea would be helpful with some code provided !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Form[] myForm3 = new Form[3] ;
```

You need to initialize the array

Comment: @rtmatchbox nothing that I am aware of